# Java Swing GUI changing the LAF

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I'm learning about making GUI using swing at the moment, and am getting frustrated trying to make a GUI for my application and making my own custom Look and Feel, using images. I have a Jframe which has a JPanel inside it(which is my application) I know how to add JmenuBar however i'm having trouble loading images to change the look and feel.

I'm trying to change the exit button, window button, and fullscreenbutton to image files and change the window bar of the application also.

Here is an example of what i'd like it to look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfKOP.png]

Any help on the subject would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: The decoration of the windows is not under your control. If you want to change it, you need to use undecorated `JFrame` and create your own title bar with the desired decoration.

Comment: I haven't made any attempts that have shown any results close to what I'm trying to do yet. Okay i will do that thank you. Will i be able to change the vertical and horizontal parts of the frame using images also?

Comment: If you use an undecorated `JFrame` you can draw everything you want on it (for example, a transparent frame, rounded edges, etc.)